# SPF Exists and Redirect

Tags: spf

I've been helping a client with their email system and realised that their webmaster entered the following as their SPF record.

```
v=spf1 exists:%{i}._spf.somedomain.com redirect=_spf.somedomain.com ?all
```

I've looked into the exists and redirect options. From what I can tell these mean that all emails sent "from" their domain would come through as authenticated with SPF?

Comment: This should definitely be asked at [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: More docs on SPF Macros: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7208#section-7

Answer (score 9):

The first part:

```
exists:%{i}._spf.somedomain.com
```

says insert the IP address, say 1.2.3.4 for example, giving:

```
exists:1.2.3.4._spf.somedomain.com
```

which says, if that DNS 'A' lookup works, it is a pass.

Having both a `redirect` and an `all` is kind of odd.
Redirect happens if everything else fails (which is why it should always be at the end of the SPF record), but `all` never fails to match.

If the `all` wasn't there the redirect:

```
redirect=_spf.somedomain.com
```

would says go fetch that SPF record process it.